# Calculate the area of the Triangle using Class and Inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, area

Hey guys I'm trying to find out the area of the triangle using the Heron's formula i.e *area= sqrt(s(s-l1)(s-l2)(s-l3))*. For this, I need to check if the given sides add up to the triangle, which I have.

However, I'm not able to figure out how to use this in the inherited class here.

What, I want to do is take input from the parent class and calculate area from the inherited class. Any help is appreciated.

*Nomenclature used* 
1) l1, l2, l3 : *sides* of the triangle
2) **Checktri** method is used to check if the given sides add up to a triangle or not
3) **Areatri** is the inherited class of **Triangledim** wherein the area need to be found out

```
import math
class Triangledim:
    def __init__(self, l1, l2, l3):
        self.l1 = l1
        self.l2 = l2
        self.l3 = l3

#Check if the given measurements form a triangle
    def checktri(self):
        if (self.l1+self.l2>self.l3) & (self.l2+self.l3>self.l1) & (self.l1+self.l3>self.l2):
            s = (self.l1 +self.l2+self.l3)/2
            return ("Perimeter of the triangle is %f" %s)
        else : 
            return("not the right triangle proportions") 

class Areatri(Triangledim):
      def __init__(self):
            Triangledim.__init__(self)
            area = math.sqrt(self.s(self.s-self.l1)(self.s-self.l2)(self.s-self.l3))
            return area


p=Triangledim(7,5,10)
```

Comment: This isn't how you  use inheritance.

Comment: I agree, i'm new to this and i'm still figuring out my way into this. So if I need to inherit the methods of the parent class, I need to use a pointer, in this case, "self" and declare my attribute there, else I can't use it into my child class? Am i right?

Comment: No, I mean there's no reason to have a class `Areatri` that inherits from `Triangledim` in the first place. `Triangledim` represents a triangle (namely, using the length of its sides). Computing the area of a triangle is something you do *to* or *with* a triangle, not something that is a *kind* of triangle (which is what inheritance is supposed to model).

Comment: Got it. Thank you, i'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is what you probably need:

```
import math

class Triangledim():

    def __init__(self, l1, l2, l3):
        self.l1 = l1
        self.l2 = l2
        self.l3 = l3
        self.s = (self.l1+self.l2+self.l3) / 2.0

    def checktri(self):
        if (self.l1+self.l2>self.l3) and (self.l2+self.l3>self.l1) and (self.l1+self.l3>self.l2): 
            print("Perimeter of the triangle is: {}".format(self.s))
        else: 
            print("not the right triangle proportions") 

    def findArea(self):
        area = math.sqrt(self.s*(self.s-self.l1)*(self.s-self.l2)*(self.s-self.l3))
        print("The area of the triangle is: {}".format(area))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Triangledim(7,5,10)
    p.checktri()
    p.findArea()
```

Output:

```
Perimeter of the triangle is: 11.0
The area of the triangle is: 16.24807680927192
```

In case you want to use heritage, the following will do the job for you:

```
import math

class Triangledim():

    def __init__(self, l1, l2, l3):
        self.l1 = l1
        self.l2 = l2
        self.l3 = l3
        self.s = (self.l1+self.l2+self.l3) / 2.0

    def checktri(self):
        if (self.l1+self.l2>self.l3) and (self.l2+self.l3>self.l1) and (self.l1+self.l3>self.l2): 
            print("Perimeter of the triangle is: {}".format(self.s))
        else: 
            print("not the right triangle proportions") 

class Areatri(Triangledim):
    def findArea(self):
        area = math.sqrt(self.s*(self.s-self.l1)*(self.s-self.l2)*(self.s-self.l3))
        print("The area of the triangle is: {}".format(area))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Areatri(7,5,10)
    p.checktri()
    p.findArea()
```

Output:

```
Perimeter of the triangle is: 11.0
The area of the triangle is: 16.24807680927192
```

Comment: That's true, I can do this too, but imagine that you need a heritage, how to solve that? What I need to understand here is, how to use self.s in a heritage?

Comment: I edited my answer and I included the same result by using heritage.

Comment: Got it, I understood now. So for the child class to derive at the s value, the s value needs to be defined as self.s? Else the child class will not be able to use it? Am I right?

Comment: okay, so no matter what you define within the method for eg **checktri** ( where i obtained the value s, will not be inherited to the child class)

Comment: You can define everything in the constructor ```__init__``` with ```self.variable```, and then carry it out to the inherited classes.